# How to include credentials in amCharts4 request?

Tags: ajax, amcharts

Using amCharts V4, how can I include cookies in the built-in API request?

I am using the amCharts external data loader as described at https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/loading-external-data/ but need to include a cookie in the request.

The equivalent in plain Javascript would be

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/api", true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

My code is currently:

```
let chart = am4core.create('chartdiv', am4charts.XYChart);
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.dataSource.url = "http://www.example.org/api";
```

Is there a "withCredentials" equivalent in amCharts 4?

Comment: Why not just use Ajax to get the data you want first, and then build the chart?

Comment: @DavidLiang, that is definitely an option and how I handled it in prior versions.  Setting dataSource.url is just so easy and clean.  No callbacks, no promises, just set it and forget it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, there is. The `dataSource` has a [`requestOptions` property](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/datasource/#requestOptions_property), it would be done there something like this:

```js
chart.dataSource.requestOptions.withCredentials = true;
```

Or if `requestOptions` is not initialized yet for some reason:

```js
chart.dataSource.requestOptions = {
    withCredentials: true
}
```

(Relevant reference if interested:

`requestOptions`' interface: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/inetrequestoptions/#withCredentials_property)

Comment: Perfect SO answer.  Correct, concise, complete and includes a link to the relevant documentation.

Comment: I really appreciate the high praise! This answer was only possible with the help of [Martynas](https://www.amcharts.com/about/), he pointed he had already implemented `withCredentials` before. Otherwise we would've made a feature request for you over on GitHub in the interim.